# Where are Teradata header files downloaded from? (DBD::Teradata build)

Tags: teradata, dbi

I am attempting to build the Perl DBD::Teradata DBI driver on 64 bit linux.  However, I do not have the header files necessary to do so.  According to the documentation (http://www.presicient.com/tdatdbd/), the following files are required:

```
parcel.h
dbcarea.h
coperr.h
coptypes.h
```

I've spent hours scouring Teradata's site and the internet at large with no success.  I saw mention of a CLIv2 developer's kit, but could not locate this either.

Could anyone point me to where I can get these files?  I would sincerely appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the headers in one of the rpm files from the cliv2 linux download.  I missed the second rpm file last time around and so I didn't find my files.

Here's the download link (as pointed out by dnoeth in comments below):
downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/cliv2/linux

if you decompress the tarball you'll find the headers in this rpm:
cliv2/cliv2-15.00.00.03-1.noarch.rpm

I am still not able to install the rpm, but I was able to pull the headers out for my DBD::Teradata build:

```
plxc16479> rpm2cpio cliv2/cliv2-15.00.00.03-1.noarch.rpm | cpio -idmv
./opt/teradata
./opt/teradata/client
./opt/teradata/client/15.00
./opt/teradata/client/15.00/include
./opt/teradata/client/15.00/include/cliv2if.h
./opt/teradata/client/15.00/include/coperr.h
./opt/teradata/client/15.00/include/coptypes.h
./opt/teradata/client/15.00/include/dbca2px.h
./opt/teradata/client/15.00/include/dbcarea.h
./opt/teradata/client/15.00/include/dbcerr.h
./opt/teradata/client/15.00/include/dbchqep.h
./opt/teradata/client/15.00/include/mosiif.h
./opt/teradata/client/15.00/include/parcel.h
```

Thanks for those that took the time to help out!

Answer (score 0):

You should have searched your PC instead :-)

Installing the Teradata Client usually includes CLI, the header files are located in the Teradata Client directory under cliv2, e.g. in Windows

C:\program files\teradata\client\14.10\cliv2\inc

If you're running a different OS you might check the [installation guide](http://www.info.teradata.com/templates/eSrchResults.cfm?prodline=&txtpid=&txtrelno=&txtttlkywrd=CINSTALL&rdsort=Title&srtord=Asc&nm=Installation)

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I do not have any such software installed on my pc and I will be building on linux.  My question is where to get the files in the first place.  All the linux downloads seem to result in rpm files that I can't install.  I will examine the install guide further and hope I find something useful.

Comment: Did you check the Linux download? http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/cliv2/linux Which distro di you use?

Comment: Apologies for the slow reply.  I did check that download, but missed that fact that there are multiple rpm files in there.  I found the headers in one I didn't check. Thanks for the help :)