# Failing to install perl DBI for Teradata on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, odbc, teradata, dbi

I have strawberry perl installed on Windows and i need Teradata drivers. I downloaded the package from here: http://www.presicient.com/tdatdbd/. I am having the problem following the windows install instructions:

cd to wherever you've unbundled the DBD-Teradata-XXX.tar.gz file, and then cd to the DBD-Teradata-XXX directory. Run the usual Perl package installation process, namely 
perl Makefile.PL
nmake
nmake install

nmake is a part of the Visual Studio toolset; a free standalone version is available.

The link to the free standalone version of nmake is broken, and downloading Visual Studio is failing. So I found a page where a user used dmake in place of name. Using dmake fails for me with

```
G:\ACC-ADMIN\PRA\Perl\DBD-Teradata-1.52>dmake
gcc -c  -IC:\PROGRA~1\NCR\TERADA~1\cli\inc      -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 - DCONSERVATIVE -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS
 -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2      -DVERSION=\"1.52\"
  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"   Teradata.c
**Teradata.xs:5:22: fatal error: coptypes.h: No such file or directory**
 #include "coptypes.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
dmake:  Error code 129, while making 'Teradata.o'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: "The link to the free standalone version of nmake is broken" Instead of just giving up and moving on to the next tool, maybe you should try to find another link that does work. See [Where do I find nmake for Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/146577/where-do-i-find-nmake-for-windows-7). Not that it will help in this case...you're missing some required header files. See [Where are Teradata header files downloaded from? (DBD::Teradata build)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24747452/176646)

Comment: My end goal is to have something that's easily installable onto multiple windows machines. Once I get the required headers and complete the 'make install' step, will I get something that's portable to other machines, or will I need to compile for each machine that's getting the install?  I'm trying to keep the steps needed to install to a minimum. Seems like now I'm down to 1. install perl 2. download DBI teradata 3. download the missing headers 4. find a working nmake or dmake; 5. run "make install" to get Teradata DBI installed

Comment: You probably want to use the perl  ODBC DBI module to connect to Teradata and use the official Teradata ODBC driver https://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/odbc-driver/windows

Comment: Yes, I did that first, but that did not contain the Teradata drivers I need according to my perl output. install_driver(Teradata) failed: Can't locate DBD/Teradata.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBD::Terada
ns: C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib C:/Strawberry/perl/lib .) at (eval 5) line 3.
Perhaps the DBD::Teradata perl module hasn't been fully installed,
or perhaps the capitalisation of 'Teradata' isn't right.
Available drivers: ADO, CSV, DBM, ExampleP, File, Gofer, ODBC, Oracle, Pg, Proxy, SQLite, Sponge, mysql.
 at pl.pl line 6.